# Can't find npm version -- "Cannot read property 'node' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, version, npm, zombie-process

I've installed a few node modules using npm (express, handlebars, mocha, chai). I know it's working. When I run `npm install --save-dev zombie`, I get several errors. I think it's because `npm -v` isn't working. When I enter that command, I get `[TypeError: Cannot read property 'node' of undefined]`. What might cause this? What is it saying is undefined? Here's the output after the zombie install command above.

```
npm WARN package.json gizworks@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json gizworks@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json gizworks@0.0.0 No README data
npm ERR! TypeError: Invalid Version: TypeError: Cannot read property 'node' of undefined
npm ERR!     at new SemVer (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/semver/semver.js:262:11)
npm ERR!     at compare (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/semver/semver.js:456:10)
npm ERR!     at gte (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/semver/semver.js:505:10)
npm ERR!     at cmp (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/semver/semver.js:522:22)
npm ERR!     at Comparator.test (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/semver/semver.js:592:10)
npm ERR!     at testSet (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/semver/semver.js:926:17)
npm ERR!     at Range.test (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/semver/semver.js:918:9)
npm ERR!     at Function.satisfies (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/semver/semver.js:939:16)
npm ERR!     at checkEngine (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-install-checks/index.js:13:29)
npm ERR!     at Array.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/bind-actor.js:15:8)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.3.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--save-dev" "zombie"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/Taylor/developer/mean/gizworks
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v TypeError: Cannot read property 'node' of undefined
npm ERR! npm -v     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:48:38
npm ERR! npm -v     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:461:3)
npm ERR! npm -v     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
npm ERR! npm -v     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
npm ERR! npm -v     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
npm ERR! npm -v     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
npm ERR! npm -v     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
npm ERR! npm -v     at require (module.js:380:17)
npm ERR! npm -v     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:24:11
npm ERR! npm -v     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:86:3)
npm ERR! npm -v  [TypeError: Cannot read property 'node' of undefined]
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Taylor/developer/mean/gizworks/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved on [github](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5891). I somehow replaced /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/package.json and had to reinstall npm to get a fresh one.